# How to include file url in msg-template of pylint?

Tags: configuration, pycharm, pylint

I would like to make the file paths of the pylint output clickable, so that I can open the corresponding file location. I tried to use following msg-template in the PyCharm terminal on Windows:

```
msg-template='(file:///{abspath}:{line}) :{column}: {msg_id}: {msg} ({symbol})'
```

[image]

However, on Windows I have backward \ instead of forward / slashes and the hyperlink does not work.

=> How can I include the file path as valid url/uri?

Comment: I created a feature request for pylint: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3886

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to specify file:/// on Windows. Try this:

```
--msg-template="{abspath}:{line} :{column}: {msg_id}: {msg} {symbol}"
```

[image]